# How to show loader and empty data layout in paging 3 android studio

Tags: android, paging, loader

I want to show loader when data is loading and when data loaded the loader will be dismiss.
if their is no data means black or empty list then show a empty message layout screen in paging 3 android .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is below code solve my problem .

```
private fun observeConsultations() {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {

        viewModel.getConsultationList().collectLatest{
            launch(Dispatchers.Main){
                adapter.loadStateFlow.collectLatest { loadStates ->
                    if (loadStates.refresh is LoadState.Loading ){
                        loader.show()
                    }
                    else{
                        loader.dismiss()
                        if (loadStates.refresh is LoadState.Error){
                            if ( adapter.itemCount < 1){
                                binding.clNoConsult.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            }else{
                                binding.clNoConsult.visibility = View.GONE
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            adapter.submitData(it)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Really! what is going on here?

Comment: @AjithkumarMuthukumaran here i am notify the latest state of this adapter . first of all check the state is loading or not if loading show loader, if state is no loading then dismiss the loader and check the data list , here if data list is empty then it return the error show whenever getting this error we will show our empty data message screen like above code . if this answer resolve your problem please upvote the answer